# Change background of all the textblocks in a Page to Transparent by clicking on a textblock and change the background of clicked textblock to Blue

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have my problem half solved.

Look at the below code:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="Blue" Duration="0:0:0.100" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

As you can see in the above style, I can change the background of a clicked textblock to Blue. But I also want to change the background of other textblocks to Transparent.

Comment: Why you using TextBlock for MouseDown and All these events. I think TextBlock/Label are used to Display Data in ReadOnly mode that cant be altered by user interactions with these controls.I hope i make my point clear

Comment: My client wants to set the margins and alignments for each control in my application himself. So, I need him to select one of the textblock / any other control and then I will give him property grid to set those properties that he wants.

Comment: Do you have snapshot of it? if you do thn please show

Comment: I do not have it. But the idea is to make a copy of the designer of visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

It seems u want to change  style of only selected textblock . You can use listbox for your requirement as listbox item is having style for selected and unselected item.
Maybe I am wrong..but try this.this is might be helpful. 
I have used different color in style ..You can use own colors as per  your requirement

```
<Style x:Key="listbox_Item" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Margin="10" x:Name="BorderStyle" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1"/>
                        <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>                                                                        
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="false">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="unselectedAnimation">
                                    <Storyboard >
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderStyle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color" From="Transparent" To="Green" Duration="0:0:0.1"></ColorAnimation>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="unselectedAnimation" />
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="selectedAnimation">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <Storyboard >
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderStyle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color" From="Transparent" To="Red" Duration="0:0:0.1"></ColorAnimation>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="selectedAnimation"/>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                         Value="Red"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

and behind code u need to create a class and itemsouce for listbox

```
 InitializeComponent();
        List<tileproperty> abc = new List<tileproperty>();
        abc.Add(new tileproperty("ssss", "dssds"));
        abc.Add(new tileproperty("ssss", "dssds"));                      
        lst.ItemsSource = abc;
    }
public class tileproperty
{
    public string next { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
    public tileproperty(string next, string path)
    {
        this.next = next;
        this.path = path;
    }

}
```